# Can the AutoIt array initializer handle different datatypes?

Tags: multidimensional-array, initialization, autoit

I'm currently facing a strange problem for which I can't find the reason. I'm trying to create a multidimensional array in AutoIt and initialize it with values. Keeping the variant datatype in mind, it should be possible to create  an array, that

- consists of multiple elements (of course)
- each element is another array containing exactly 2 elements (with different types)
- these two elements are a single integer and another array with 4 integers

So basically I want to have an array of key/value pairs where the value is an array of numbers. I know that the "value" in this case is treated as a simple variable and not as an directly accessible array - that is what I want.

However, if I try

```
Global Const $x[3][2] = [ _
                          [1, [11,12,13,14] ], _
                          [2, [21,22,23,24] ], _
                          [3, [31,32,33,34] ] _
                        ]
```

I just get

```
error: syntax error
                    [1, [
                    ~~~~^
error: syntax error
                    [2, [
                    ~~~~^
error: syntax error
                    [3, [
                    ~~~~^
```

Either I'm missing something or the initializer doesn't realize that I don't want to have 3 dimensions but just 2 and handle the 4 item array as a single variant.

**Can anybody suggest the preferred solution for that?** Or should I forget this combined solution and simple go with an array of arrays with 5 elements each, like

```
Global Const $x[3][5] = [ _
                          [1, 11,12,13,14 ], _
                          [2, 21,22,23,24 ], _
                          [3, 31,32,33,34 ] _
                        ]
```

and handle the difference in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but you need to initialise the inner arrays separately.

```
Global $arr[3][2]
Global $a1[4] = [11,12,13,14]  ;these are the inner arrays
Global $a2[4] = [21,22,23,24]
Global $a3[4] = [31,32,33,34] 
$arr[0][0] = 1
$arr[0][1] = $a1 ;put the inner arrays into the outer array
$arr[1][0] = 2
$arr[1][1] = $a2
$arr[2][0] = 3
$arr[2][1] = $a3

Global $arrTemp
For $i = 0 to UBound($arr)-1
    $arrTemp = $arr[$i][1]
    For $j = 0 To UBound($arrTemp)-1
        ConsoleWrite($arr[$i][0] & ': ' & $arrTemp[$j] & @CRLF)
    Next
Next
```

This will output:

```
1: 11
1: 12
1: 13
1: 14
2: 21
2: 22
2: 23
2: 24
3: 31
3: 32
3: 33
3: 34
```

Comment: This doesn't help me, as I already have 2 arrays initialized separately, but rather want a combined solution. However, it does answer the question - so I'll go for the 5 item approach ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. You can got for this:

```
#region    ;************ Includes ************
#include <Array.au3>
#endregion    ;************ Includes ************

Global $a[4] = [11, 12, 13, 14]
Global Const $x[3][2] = [ _
        [1, $a], _
        [2, "21,22,23,24"], _
        [3, "31,32,33,34"] _
        ]

_ArrayDisplay($x)

; Getting the values of [0][1]
For $i = 0 To UBound($a) - 1
    ConsoleWrite($a[$i] & @CR)
Next

$re = StringSplit($x[1][1], ',', 2)
For $i = 0 To UBound($re) - 1
    ConsoleWrite($re[$i] & @CR)
Next
```

Comment: This doesn't help me, as I already have 2 arrays initialized separately, but rather want a combined solution. However, it does answer the question - so I'll go for the 5 item approach ...